# Checking if value is present in the list of key-value pairs, if not present then add the new key-pair value from iterables (not overwriting same key)

Tags: python, append, iterable

If I used the `not in` it still appends the new key-pair value even if a specific value is already in the list.

```
    dict1 = {'a': 0, 'a': 5, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
    list1 = [{'a': 0}] # This key-pair value is already in the list1 but 
                       # still added from dict1.

    new1 = []
    new2 = []
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if value not in list1:
            new1.append(key)
            new2.append(value)

    new0 = {new1[i]: new2[i] for i in range(len(new1))}
    list1.append(new0)
```

Desired output is:

```
    list1 = [{'a': 0, 'a': 5, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}]
```

(As I dont want to overwrite the key/s)

Comment: Can you provide some example data? What's the current result and what would be your desired outcome?

Comment: That's because you append tuples (key, value), lo list2 is a list of pairs. "value" is a single item and it is not found among the pairs.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Thank you for the edit. Its my first time here. Been searching in google for days now... I edited it already. Hope it helps to specify my problem.

Comment: @GiovanniTardini I see. I thought that using 'value' alone will scan over list2 and will identify if the value really exist in the list.

Comment: @GiovanniTardini 'value' is whats used to scan over list2 and then add the key and value pair if the value is not found. I hope this helps others who want to find answer too. I was searching for days already binging on google. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not provide example data, I have to make some guesses here. If I guessed incorrectly, please provide the required information.

You call `.items` on `list1`. A list does not have a `items` function. Instead, I suspect your `list1` is actually a dictionary, which would like this for example:

```
list1 = {
    "a":1, 
    "b":2,
    "c":3
}
```

In your current loop, you check if the value is within `list2`. If `list2` is actually a list, you're doing so correctly. However, based on your title I assume what you actually want to do is check if the key is in `list2`, and if not add the key:value to `list2`. You could not add a key:value pair to a list, so I assume that `list2` shoudl also be a dictionary. You would be able to add them add as a tuple, but based on the title I assume that is not what you want.

If you actually want to add it as a key:value pair to a dictionary, you could do that as follows:

```
list2 = {}
for key, value in list1.items():
    if key not in list2.keys(): # check if this key already exists
        list2[key] = value # if not, add they key with the value
```

As `list1` and `list2` are not actually instances of `list`, but of `dict` I would recommend renaming your variables to avoid future confusion.  Hope that helps!

**EDIT after update in question**

Your example data had a small mistake, as there were two `a` keys, meaning that the first `{'a':0}` would be overwritten within `dict1` already.

```
dict1 = {'a': 0, 'b': 5, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}
list1 = [{'a': 0}]
```

As I understand it, you wish to check if the value is already containted within a list of dictionaries.
As such, we need to get all the values from these dictionaries.

As you do not want to overwrite any keys, it would need to be a list of dictionaries that each only have one key. As such, we can get each individual dictionary, get the keys. This returns an `dict_keys` object, which we can convert to a list. Since each dictionary within `list1` always only has one key, we can just take the first from said lsit.

```
[list(x.values())[0] for x in list1]
```

Putting that within the loop we get

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if not value in [list(x.values())[0] for x in list1]:
    # If no dictionary exists within `list1` with this value
        list1.append({key:value}) # then add it as a new dictionary
```

This would return

```
[{'a': 0}, {'b': 5}, {'c': 1}, {'d': 2}]
```

You could run this code again with a different `dict1` and it would not overwrite keys within `list1`, for example with:

```
dict1 = {'a': 9}
```

the output would become

```
[{'a': 0}, {'b': 5}, {'c': 1}, {'d': 2}, {'a': 9}]
```

Comment: Yes you are correct about the dict and list variables, my bad. This answer is almost correct but I wanna check using the value, checking if the value exist in list2 and if doesnt, append both the key and value.

Comment: I see. So in other words, a dictionary with unique values? Or a list, containing dictionaries, where the values in all those dictionaries are unique?

Comment: "Or a list, containing dictionaries, where the values in all those dictionaries are unique?" This is specifically correct.